# NSSegmentedControl highlighting with blue tint and single-selection

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nssegmentedcontrol, nscontrol

Is there a documented way for an `NSSegmentedControl` to use the trackingMode `NSSegmentSwitchTrackingSelectOne` (i.e. exclusively select one segment in the control) and have it **rendered using the blue tint highlighting mode** - the one we get automatically when using `NSSegmentSwitchTrackingSelectAny`?

What I’m looking for is a style similar to the one seen in **Xcode’s toolbar** or **Navigator** sub tool bar/switcher:

[image]

Attempts so far using either different styles or poking around the headers didn’t turn up anything -
the segmented control is rendered with dark grey highlighting (similar to the one observed in Finder windows).

Any hints on how to activate the blue highlighting mode much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I am not sure if this is the right way to do, but you could create two versions of each image. One for selected and normal state. Then you can switch the images once the control is clicked.

Comment: ouch ;-) I'd rather use the select many mode and manually handle mutually exclusive selection… still, it would be cool to find the system supported way.

Comment: toggling between these two images (blue and grey) is only possible programatically, not in IB, correct?